# VBA fill cells by random numbers depending on other cells

Tags: vba, excel, fill

I am working with Excel 2013 and I need to fill the range of cells by random numbers. To be exact, Range(B1:B4) fill by numbers in order to value of cells in previous column, I mean in Range(A1:A4). I really have no idea how to fill that using VBA if there is that condition, otherwise it's simple.

Here is a scetch of cells

```
# |    A     |   B   |
----------------------
1 |   Yes    |   1   |
----------------------
2 |   No     |   2   |
----------------------
3 |   Maybe  |   3   |
----------------------
4 |   No     |   2   |
----------------------
```

Comment: I'ts not clear what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is **set this with vba**, this should give you values 1, 2, or 3:

```
Range("B1:B4").Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,3)"
```

If you only need an **Excel formula**, you can always just paste `=RANDBETWEEN(1,3)` into the formula bar.

If you're trying to **define column B values based on column A** values, just use:

```
Range("B1:B4").Formula = "=IF(A1 = ""Yes"", 1, IF(""No"", 2, If(""Maybe"", 3, ""ERROR"")))"
```

If neither of those are what you want, you're going to have to clarify better.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is random numbers, you don't need VBA. Just set your cell formula equal to:

```
"=RANDBETWEEN(1,3)"
```

However, your random numbers will change every time your worksheet is calculated. To avoid this, you can define the following sub and associate it, for example, with an action button:

```
Sub makeRand()

    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim xlCell As Range
    Dim upperBound As Integer
    Dim lowerBound As Integer


    Set targetRange = Range("B1:B4")
    upperBound = 3
    lowerBound = 1

    Randomize

    For Each xlCell In targetRange
        xlCell.Value = Int((upperBound - lowerBound + 1) * Rnd + lowerBound)
    Next xlCell


End Sub
```